# Bat echo output code PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a bat script with this line :

```
echo ($a = (quser) -replace "\s{2,}" , ";" | Select-String -pattern console -notmatch | Select-string -pattern ID -notmatch)>>ScriptV3.ps1
```

but when I launch this line, my bat search to recognize pipe `|`, but here, pipe are to my PowerShell script.

How can I hidden this pipe for my batch script but i find this pipe in my PowerShell script.

Thank you !

PS : if I write :

```
echo "$a = (quser) -replace "\s{2,}" , ";" | Select-String -pattern console -notmatch | Select-string -pattern ID -notmatch">>ScriptV3.ps1
```

with quote, work in batch but doesn't work in PowerShell :(

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  It would have been easier on everyone if you had shown the resulting ps1 file and explained what you wanted it to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
echo ($a = (quser) -replace "\s{2,}" , ";" ^| Select-String -pattern console -notmatch ^| Select-string -pattern ID -notmatch)>>ScriptV3.ps1
```

pipe redirection is with higher priority than the echo and needs to be escaped.